# Youtube Data Api v3 search list return nothing

Tags: youtube-data-api

recently, the search list api (event type: live) return nothing

example: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&eventType=live&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

return

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/jg2CTBtu0DNa8PVkxeurAMgwBzc\"",
 "regionCode": "TW",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
 ]
}
```

does anyone has this problem too?

this api used to can get live channel, but it return nothing now

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/code_snippets

use this tool, choose parameter to "search live event" also return nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the result dude at 
    `https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it`.
Some times it does not work means, developer is improving api, or may be server problem. Its not a big thing.

Comment: could you set "eventType" to "live" and "type" to "video", I only get nothing when I want to get live channel list.

Comment: Yes, I have it just try your self or may be your key is not vaild anymore.